# Solving for x: $2\cdot 4^ { x } - 3\cdot 10^ { x } - 5\cdot 25^ { x } = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$2\cdot 4^ { x } - 3\cdot 10^ { x } - 5\cdot 25^ { x } = 0$$

Can not understand this equality

Comment: try to factor the bases of the exponentials

Comment: It's an *equation* not an equality

Answer (score 2):

Hint: divide by $4^x$ then use substitution $u=(\frac{5}{2})^x$

Comment: я говорю по русский @Vasya

Comment: me too, but my PC does not :)

Answer (score 1):

$u=2^x, v = 5^x,$
$$ 2 u^2 - 3 u v - 5 v^2 = 0, $$
$$ (2u - 5v)(u +v ) = 0 $$
$u$ and $v$ are positive, so $2u - 5 v = 0,$ $2u = 5 v,$
$$ 2 \cdot 2^x = 5 \cdot 5^x $$
$$ 2^{x+1} = 5^{x+1}, $$
$$ \left( \frac{2}{5} \right)^{x+1} = 1,  $$
$x+1 = 0,$ $x=-1$